# How to Create MongoDB cluster as Docker Containers

Tags: mongodb, docker

I can able to run single instance on Mongo using the following Docker command

**docker run -it --rm -d -p 27017:27017 --user mongodb mongo:3.4**

But I can't find out how to configure Config Server and Query Router and also how add shards with Replication

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7):

I used this tutorial myself: https://medium.com/@gargar454/deploy-a-mongodb-cluster-in-steps-9-using-docker-49205e231319#.mle6a8wmg

### Step 1: create folders

create folders (local on all nodes):

```
sudo mkdir -p /dockerlocalstorage/data/mongodb
sudo mkdir -p /dockerlocalstorage/backup/mongodb
sudo mkdir -p /dockersharedstorage/config/mongodb/
```

### Step 2: create keyfile

create keyfile as root user and give correct permissions:

```
sudo su
cd /dockersharedstorage/config/mongodb/
openssl rand -base64 741 > mongodb-keyfile
chmod 600 mongodb-keyfile
sudo chown 999 mongodb-keyfile
```

Depending on the mount type you might need to use /dockerlocalstorage/ to keep the certs. Mongodb will complain if the permissions are not set correctly (which could be harder to achieve on lets say a cifs mount)

### Step 3: setup first node

create mongodb container without auth/keyfile:

```
docker run --name mongodb \
-v /dockerlocalstorage/data/mongodb:/data/db \
-v /dockersharedstorage/config/mongodb:/opt/keyfile \
--hostname="dock01" \
-p 27017:27017 \
-d mongo
```

log in to container:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongo
```

create root users, dont forget to **change the passwords**

```
use admin
db.createUser( {
     user: "admin",
     pwd: "PASSWORD",
     roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
   });

db.createUser( {
     user: "root",
     pwd: "PASSWORD",
     roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
   });
```

exit and remove the container

```
exit
docker stop mongodb
docker rm mongodb
```

### Step 4: start nodes

**change NODE_NR**:

```
docker run \
-d \
--name mongodb \
-v /dockerlocalstorage/data/mongodb:/data/db \
-v /dockerlocalstorage/backup/mongodb:/data/backup \
-v /dockersharedstore/config/mongodb:/opt/keyfile \ 
--restart=always \
--hostname="dock01" \
-p 27017:27017 mongo \
--keyFile /opt/keyfile/mongodb-keyfile \
--replSet "SET_NAME"
```

### Step 5: setup replication

connect to node 1:

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongo
use admin
db.auth("root", "PASSWORD");
```

initialize the replication set:

```
rs.initiate()
```

Check the replica set with: `rs.conf()` or `rs.status()`

add others:

```
rs.add("dock02:27017")
rs.add("dock03:27017")
```

### Step 6: setup mongodump

edit crontab:

```
sudo su
crontab -l > tempcron
```

echo new cron into cron file

```
echo "0 4 * * *  docker exec -it mongodb mongodump -u root -p PASSWORD -o /data/backup/daily"  >> tempcron
echo "30 4 * * 5 docker exec -it mongodb mongodump -u root -p PASSWORD -o /data/backup/weekly" >> tempcron
```

install new cron file

```
crontab tempcron
rm tempcron
exit
```

Comment: I am trying to follow your commands to make my cluster. But I keep running into issues with permissions especially with ```chmod 600 mongodb-keyfile
sudo chown 999 mongodb-keyfile```

When executing the docker run command - I keep getting:
I keep getting `2017-12-18T03:04:18.551+0000 I ACCESS   [main] error opening file: /opt/keyfile/mongodb-keyfile: Permission denied`

Please advice?

Comment: Chown it to the userid that runs mongo inside your container.

Comment: Thanks @p.streef running into other issue `FailedToParse: Empty host component parsing HostAndPort from \":27017\" for member:{ _id: 0, host: \":27017\" }` when running the node1 container

Answer (score 1):

You could use [docker swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) if you want docker native mongodb cluster (Docker >= 1.12 needed).

Have a look [at this nice tutorial](https://medium.com/@kalahari/running-a-mongodb-replica-set-on-docker-1-12-swarm-mode-step-by-step-a5f3ba07d06e). This will show you how to get a mongodb cluster with docker, replicated with Config Server. Basically, the steps are:

1. Create multiple virtual machines (with `docker-machine` or whatever you use to create a new docker host)
2. Create the swarm (docker cluster of multiple machines)
3. Create a swarm overlay network to deal with all your mongodb traffic
4. Create the services on each swarm node (that will create your mongodb containers on your hosts)
5. Configure your mongodb replica set

This is a bit of work, but worth it, as when you get there, you'll have tools on `docker swarm` to orchestrate your mongodb cluster.

Comment: If you use swarm mode you will also need to make sure that the data used by the container is available on all nodes. Or lock the containers to a node, which beats the purpose of using swarm. I would advice to just run without swarm mode and use mongoDB's replication for high availability

Comment: As the data is replicated, you may have containers use their own data. But true, you'll have to be sure that only one mongodb is created by node with command `--constraint 'node.labels.mongo.replica == 1'` for instance

Comment: But then what would be the advantage of swarm over non swarm? A downside would be although unlikely, if the swarm would move all containers to new nodes (lets say you have 3 replicas and 10 nodes and have to restart the cluster) you would lose your data until you manually move them back to at least one of the correct nodes (and make this one primary before replication takes over). With normal docker run I would argue you would have some more control over this. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, but I would not recommend this use case. Actually, swarm mode can be useful when you create a mongodb cluster with `global` service mode (a mongodb on each node by default). You have a swarm dedicated to mongodb only (you can operate another swarm for your web services, etc...). When you add a node, a mongodb service will be added (and automatically attached to the replica set - this is not shown in the tutorial).

Comment: Running it as a global service would do the trick i guess. I might just try this myself too!

Comment: if the mongo service is ran in mode=global, will one still need to pin the service to a specific container as shown in the tutorial?
How about data volumes in the scenario where mode=global ???